# TSC Recompiling unchanged TypeScript files

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

TSC compiles unchanged TS files in our lib folder, generating changes in our .map.js and .js files.

This gets annoying when we have several developers pushing code and we have to pull and push a bunch of new .js and .map.js files from .ts files which were not modified.

Here is a sample of a change, git diff shows that lines like these keep getting removed.

```
exports.functionName= void 0;
```

Below is our tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "pretty": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./lib",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["lib/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

All of our developers share the same tsconfig

Comment: Are you sure you want to keep the files in `/dist` in your GIT repository? I would add this path to your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: @Stanislas we need the /dist folder in the git repo.